# PySide2 - Main Window not showing and saying "Window is not responding"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I have some trouble with pyside2... Before I got it to respond, but I can't right now.. I don't know why

Here's some code:

main.py

```
app = c.QApplication(c.sys.argv)
    splash_pix = c.QPixmap("animation.gif")
    splash = c.SplashScreen("animation.gif", c.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    splash.show()
    app.processEvents()
    screen = app.primaryScreen()
    size = screen.size()
    main_window = c.Main(x=(size.width() // 2) - (500 // 2), y=(size.height() // 2) - (500 // 2))
    splash.finish(main_window)
    c.time.sleep(0.01)
    main_window.show()
    c.sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I imported the packages
"Main" is a class I made

```
class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width=500, height=500, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height = x, y, width, height
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);")
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.setGeometry(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.addWidgets()

    def addWidgets(self):
        self.welcome_label = QLabel("Test")
        self.welcome_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600;}")

        self.register_button = QPushButton("Register")
        self.register_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0.273, stop: 0 rgba(85,172,238,1), stop: 1 rgba(79, 165, 240, 1)); border-radius: 20px; color: white; font: bold 18px; min-width: 5em; min-height: 1.8em; padding: 1px;} QPushButton:hover {background-color: rgba(69, 131, 186, 1);}")
        self.register_button.clicked.connect(self.on_register)

        self.login_button = QPushButton("Login")
        self.login_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0.273, stop:0 rgba(85,172,238,1), stop:1 rgba(79, 165, 240, 1)); border-radius: 20px; color: white; font: bold 18px; min-width: 5em; min-height: 1.8em; padding: 1px;} QPushButton:hover {background-color: rgba(69, 131, 186, 1);}")
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.on_login)


        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.welcome_label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.register_button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.login_button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Comment: What is `c` and why are you using it like that? What is `SplashScreen`? Also, the `Main` class is missing the `on_login` and `on_register` methods. Please carefully [follow the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions and always ensure that you provide [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (*reproducible* means that we can even copy/paste your code and run it, possibly with any further modifications.

Comment: c is the import for the classes, SplashScreen is a method in c.

Comment: I just checked, it's not an issue with my code

Comment: I tried using an example; also didn't show the window.. must be an installation bug? or something...

Comment: I'm using cv2 and pyside2 together..

Comment: 1. Please avoid multiple short comments (as the tour - which you still seem to have not followed yet - reports, this is not a chat nor a forum); 2. "c is the import for the classes" doesn't mean a lot: we didn't know what you actually did in that file, for what we knew you could have changed the names or behavior of existing classes; 3. "SplashScreen is a method in c": that is really *not* helpful. What does it? I know that you solved the issue, but keep these things in mind for future reference: we must have a valid and complete context in questions, we cannot just "guess".

Comment: For instance, if you'd correctly specified and clarified the points above from start (by also providing an *actual* MRE), we could've asked on what OS are you on since the beginning: Big Sur is known to have created lots of issues in the last weeks on multiple scenarios, softwares and frameworks, including PyQt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, nevermind, I found the answer... Big Sur apparently messes up with PyQT.
Fix here: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/pyqt5-and-big-sur.2260773/
Basically run `export QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER=1` before running the program.
Such a weird bug..

Comment: Really weird. Thanks for the answer, solve my problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem with MacOS 11.0.1 Big Sur and PySide2 5.15.1 and 5.15.2 (it is mentioned in the internet that it was fixed for PyQt 5.15.2 but apparently this isn't the case for PySide2). I confirm solution with QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER, I did it this way:

```
import os
os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'
```